# Index out of range in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!
var taskArray: [Task]? = nil

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell") as! mainCell

    taskArray = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()

    let task = taskArray![indexPath.row]

    cell.titleLabel.text = task.title
    //cell.dateLabel.text = String(task.date)

    return cell
}
```

I always get the error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" on this line: let task = taskArray![indexPath.row]. Could anybody help me out?

Comment: Please, don't post code with so many gaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send array count here , don't return a static number as it may exceed the array count

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return taskArray.count
}
```

// also convert

```
var taskArray = [Task]()
```

//

fetching should be in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad()  {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   taskArray = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()
}
```

not inside `cellForRowAt`